# What are different between MRF and Total variation in noise removal?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a general question in image processing. I have a noisy image. I would like to classify the noisy image into some regions. Two famous approaches which can use

1. MRF/Gibbs MRF: model the spatial dependence between neighborhood pixels
2. Total variation: key idea maybe based on smallest variation of image.

My question is: Could you tell me what are different between two approaches for noise removal? Which one is better? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MRF gives you a framework to do discrete optimization of problems, which respect the Markovian property, that is a pixel is conditioned only on the neighboring ones (roughly stated). Typical applications include binary or multi-class labeling problems. Total variation on the other hand, is generally used as a regularization by adding the integral of the absolute gradient of the signal/image to the energy functional. This helps to neglect irrelevant detail and focus on important ones.

We cannot say one is better than the other, as they are not exactly contradictory things. It depends on the application and the energy function you use in the MRFs.